# Select com pyodbc

Tags: sql, python, select, pyodbc

Estou tentando utilizar a string que obtenho de um Entry e um OptionMenu para realizar a pesquisa no SqlServer mas da o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Aqui está o codigo da funçao que executa a chamada:

```
def checkin(self):
    veri = self.cur.execute("select %s.id_aluno "
                            "from alunos,%s"
                            " where %s.id_aluno = alunos.matricula" % self.variavel.get() % self.variavel.get() % self.variavel.get() )
    print(veri)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só deve usar um `%` depois da string e passar uma tupla:

```
def checkin(self):
    veri = self.cur.execute("select %s.id_aluno "
                            "from alunos,%s"
                            " where %s.id_aluno = alunos.matricula" % (self.variavel.get(), self.variavel.get(), self.variavel.get()) )
    print(veri)
```